# How can I convert a hex number to integer in SQL, when the resulting value is larger than bigint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a hex number in string form, for example, 0x47423f34b640c3eb6e2a18a559322d68. When I try to convert this to an int, for comparison with another value that is an int, I run up against the BIGINT size limit. I've tried various methods such as decimal, etc, but dont seem to be able to get past the 64bit size limit.

Ideally, I'd like a conversion that converts from a hex string, to an int string, so I can bypass the int limits. However, doing this without using intermediate conversions (to values that are out of range) is causing me some problems.

An alternative solution would be to be able to convert from a decimal string (the other comparison value, which in the example given, is 94719161261466374640962917648041127272), to hex, or to binary, for comparison. I already have a routine that can convert arbitrary length hex strings to binary without overflowing intermediate variables, but I haven't had much luck doing decimal strings to binary without using intermediate variables, so I can't currently compare them that way either.

I already have a c# based solution for this conversion, so I could use SQL CLR or other similar solutions, but I'd much prefer a native SQL method for doing this conversion (decimal string to hex string or binary string, or hex string to decimal string or binary string).

Comment: Technically it should be possible to do in pure T-SQL, but I would write a CLR function.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server 2008 release updated the [See CONVERT() here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=SQL.100).aspx) function to be able to convert hexadecimal values:

```
select convert(bigint, convert (varbinary(8), '0x0000010d1858798c', 1))
```

Result:

```
1155754654092 (decimal) ( ==  0x0000010d1858798c )
```

Comment: That is not what they asked

Comment: this is only simple conversion other thing should do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer attempt, but this uses BIGINT, and as stated, my inputs are bigger than BIGINT.